# Add transaction fee to the EOS private network

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain

As it's said, EOS is a flexible blockchain network that we are free to change the parts. As you can check on [config.hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/config.hpp), we can change all the policies and systems.
The thing I'm looking for is adding a transaction fee mechanism to my EOS private network.

Is that sane or should I fork another blockchain that has a transaction fee itself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the charge is only the Token issued by yourself, you can customize the deployment of your own Token contract, and then deduct the corresponding handling fee when transferring

Comment: Thanks for the consideration. Yes, and, how?

Comment: Modify the Token contract and deduct the corresponding amount of handling fee when transferring

Comment: Well, before that I was assuming that it's impossible.